# How can I create relational ordered data combining two columns in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I want to merge two relational column in the same table into one column according to their order relation by using a hierachy logic. Every row holds `currentstate` and `nextstate`. And these two columns has a relation about ordering. 
 To illustrate;

```
id     currentstate   nextstate
 1     1              2
 2     4              5
 3     2              3
 4     3              4
 5     5              6
 6     6              9
 7     9              15
 8     15             15
```

Expected result when applied correct solution;

```
stateflow
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
15
```

Which approach should I follow to obtain this result?

Comment: how do you get the first state? what's the order?

Comment: First state is the smallest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a query based on Gordon's answer

```
with cte as (
      select currentstate, nextstate, 1 as ord
      from table1
      where currentstate = (SELECT MIN(currentstate) FROM table1)
      union all
      select t.currentstate, t.nextstate, ord + 1
      from cte
      inner join table1 t
           on cte.nextstate = t.currentstate
      where cte.nextstate <> cte.currentstate
     )
select currentstate AS stateflow
from cte
order by ord
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e032/11)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a recursive cte.  Something like this:

```
with cte as (
      select currentstate, nextstate, 1 as ord
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.nextstate = t.currentstate)
      union all
      select cte.currentstate, t.nextstate, ord + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.nextstate = t.currentstate
      where t.nextstate <> t.currentstate
     )
select *
from cte
order by ord;
```

Note: This assumes that there are no cycles and assigns the ordering based on the shortest path from the source nodes to the final node.

The `where` clause is needed to remove the cycle.

Comment: Errors:Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Ambiguous column name 'nextstate'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Ambiguous column name 'currentstate'.
When I try to change in this way:
cte.nextstate <> cte.currentstate
It gives; The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. (Data is the same with my question)